# how to deploying django web app using zeet.co

Tags: python

Even though I have no project in my account, while trying to deploy my web app in AWS Cloud, I got this message:

> Delete this cloud
>
> Please ensure there are no projects using this account

It then redirects me back to zeet.co. It only give the message above instead of deploy it. Any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.